# python SMPP 3.4 как держать постоянное соединение с сервером

Tags: python, smpp

Здравствуйте,
Подскажите пожалуйста как держать постоянное соединение с SMPP сервером. Чтоб каждый раз при отправке сообщений не соединялся. Буду рад всем комментариям ссылкам.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Сложно советовать, не видя реализации. Могу только дать абстрактный совет.
Чтобы соединение держалось активным, в протоколе предусмотрено кое-что:

> Protocol Specification v3.4
>   **4.11. Операция "ENQUIRE_LINK”**   И ESME, и SMSC может посылать это сообщение. Оно используется для обеспечивания проверки доверия канала
>   связи между ESME и SMSC. По получении этого запроса получающая сторона
>   должна ответить с enquire_link_resp,  проверяя таким образом, что
>   функционирует подключение уровня приложения между SMSC и ESME. ESME
>   может также ответить, посылая любой допустимый SMPP примитив
>   (базисныйэлемент).

Таким образом, после установки соединения нужно запрограммировать систематическую отправку команды ENQUIRE_LINK при простое. С какой частотой - нужно уточнять у оператора сети, у всех по-разному.

Answer (score 0):

Средствами стандартной библиотеки нельзя поддерживать открытое соединение. Как и нельзя поддерживать открытое ожидающее SMTP соединение (`IDLE`).

Comment: для себя открыл очень удобный сервис для работы с почтой: [context.io](https://context.io/). нормальной библиотеки для серьезной работы с почтой под питон нет

Answer (score 0):

Выполняйте команду `enquire_link` с интервалами меньшими чем таймаут установленный на сервере. Вот рабочий пример с использованием [smpplib](https://github.com/python-smpplib/python-smpplib).

```
import smpplib
from smpplib import smpp

from time import sleep

def ping(client: smpplib.client.Client):
    p = smpp.make_pdu('enquire_link', client=client)
    client.send_pdu(p)
    return client.read_pdu()

client = smpplib.client.Client("127.0.0.1","2775")
client.connect()
client.bind_transceiver(system_id="a", password="a")

# для целей этого примера
# у сервера сконфигурирован таймаут 10 секунд
for i in range(3):
   sleep(5)
   ping(client)  # посылаем команды каждые 5 секунд - все ок

sleep(12)
# следующая команда не сработает и бросит исключение 
# smpplib.exceptions.ConnectionError так как после предыдущей
# прошло больше 10 секунд и значит мы превысили таймаут
ping(client)
```

То есть чтоб соединение не закрывалось нужно вызывать `ping` периодически, чтоб соединение не закрывалось. Это нужно делать, если вы не вызывали `listen`, а просто держите соединение открытым и не ожидаете сообщений от сервера. Функция `listen`, по-умолчанию, сама посылает `enquire_link`.